# Typescript: Escaping characters not interpreted

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, escaping

I get a string from my backend like this : `test\, another test` (send by JSON format). For this example, I will call this variable `dataReceive`.

```
let myString: string = dataReceive;
console.log(myString);                      // "test\, another test"
console.log(myString.constructor.name);     // "String"
let myTmpString: string = "test\, another test";
console.log(myTmpString);                   // "test, another test"
console.log(myTmpString.constructor.name);  // "String"
```

So, my problem is the following : How can I interpret correctly `myString` to get a correct String with all escaping characters interpreted ?

Comment: Why does it have a backslash in it in the first place?!

Comment: If a string contains a backslash, then it's a string containing a backslash as a regular character. A *string literal* requires backslashes to escape certain characters to disambiguate from special meaning *in their context as string literal*. Meaning, a string literal in source code delimited by quotes (`"foo"`) must escape any quotes within it by necessity (`"foo"bar"` is ambiguous/invalid syntax). So, again, why is there a backslash in the string in the first place if it's not meant to be part of the string?

Comment: It's not interpreted because it's part of the contents of the string. What if somebody ***meant*** to write `test\, another test`? Like I did right here in my comment. You wouldn't want Javascript to automatically interpret and remove that. String literal interpretation only happens in *string literals* in source code.

Comment: Ok,I understand. So the problem is not in my Typescript part but in my backend.

Comment: Yes. Your backend is including superfluous escaping characters.